# All DCs fail DNS:RReg test, Reports SRV Records Missing on PDC - They are present

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns, srv-record, msdcs

**Background**

We are currently in the process of doing several Domain Controller upgrades.  Before I started here a previous Admin had started the process of moving our DCs from 2008 R2 Standard to 2008 R2 Enterprise.  There was a PDC, DC2008S-0, and one additional DC, DC2008E-1 running.  There was a 3rd 2008 Enterprise DC that was sitting on a VM that was shutdown.  ALL of this was a leftover project from upgrading the DCs from 2003.  The previous admin felt that Standard was not enough for the DCs and that those licenses were purchased in error, so after floating two standard DCs the enterprise DC was added and a standard DC was demoted.

The Enterprise DC was not replicating SYSVOL at all. The MSDCS zone was missing on the Enterprise DC as well. There was also some meta-data cleanup that had to occur for the fully tombstoned DC (the spare 2008E that was sitting on a shutdown VM).  After quite a bit of troubleshooting we did an authoritative restore from the PDC.  Afterwards SYSVOL appeared to be replicating properly, we added MSDCS manually and all the records pulled in.  This was probably 8 or 9 months ago.  Everything has been working smoothly since; logins, gpo replication, new gpos, new AD accounts - as well as a Hybrid migration to O365, and all the AD sync and Dir sync stuff worked great as well.

After that time period we've returned to this DC project.  My task list was as follows:

Update the functional level of the Domain and Forest from 2003 to 2008 (this included migrating from FRS to DFRS)
Nuke the shutdown 2nd Enterprise DC, reinstall it, give it a DC role and add it to the domain.
Move FSMO roles, etc to the first Enterprise DC and make it the PDC.
Decommission the Standard DC.

I am on the precipice of decommissioning the standard DC when this DNS RReg issue came to light.  I don't believe it existed after the replication of SYSVOL and AD and DNS items, but I could be wrong.

---

**Current Issue**

All of our DCs are failing the RReg test from DCDIAG.

This is our only failure when checking DC health with DCDIAG against each DC.  When running the gui AD Replication Status Tool v1.0 as well as two PS scripts from TechNET, the AD and SYSVOL Replication/Latency Convergence Checks.

Here is the failure output from DCDIAG DNS tests

```
     Summary of DNS test results:


                                        Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext
        _________________________________________________________________
        Domain: domain.com

           DC2008S-0                    PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS FAIL n/a  
           DC2008E-0                    PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS FAIL n/a  
           DC2008E-1                    PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS FAIL n/a  

     Total Time taken to test all the DCs:2 min. 55 sec.

     ......................... domain.com failed test DNS
```

The failures are all in regards to a single CNAME, and single A record, and multiple SRV records on the new PDC DC2008E-0

```
  Starting test: DNS
     Test results for domain controllers:

        DC: DC2008E-0.domain.com
        Domain: domain.com


           TEST: Records registration (RReg)
              Network Adapter [00000007] vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter:
                 Warning:
                 Missing CNAME record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 7ae71958-74b2-4dc3-bf0e-224ec881bafa._msdcs.domain.com

                 Warning:
                 Missing A record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 DC2008E-0.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.5f315a51-10e4-4785-a4db-50312543bf35.domains._msdcs.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _kerberos._tcp.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _kerberos._udp.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _kpasswd._tcp.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.siteName._sites.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _kerberos._tcp.siteName._sites.dc._msdcs.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.siteName._sites.dc._msdcs.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _kerberos._tcp.siteName._sites.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.domain.com

                 Warning:
                 Missing A record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 gc._msdcs.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _gc._tcp.siteName._sites.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.siteName._sites.gc._msdcs.domain.com

                 Error:
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.domain.com

           Error: Record registrations cannot be found for all the network adapters

     Summary of DNS test results:

                                        Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext
        _________________________________________________________________
        Domain: domain.com
           DC2008E-0                   PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS FAIL n/a

     ......................... domain.com failed test DNS
```

---

**Investigation So Far**

I have manually inspected all these records and I can confirm that all the records exist on all my DCs.

I have also compared the MCDCS zone on all the DCs and all other records match.

The Zone Serial number on the SOA match on all DCs, this is true for all zones on all DCs as well, not just the MCDCS zone.

I'm not sure if this is best way to express that I can find the records manually, but I ran NSLOOKUP against all three DCs for one of the records listed above and it appears that it is found on all three.

```
c:\Users\userName\Desktop\replication>nslookup -type=SRV _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.domain.com
Server:  DC2008E-0.domain.com
Address:  10.1.1.27

_ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.domain.com     SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = DC2008E-0.domain.com
DC2008E-0.domain.com        internet address = 10.1.1.27

c:\Users\userName\Desktop\replication>nslookup -type=SRV _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.domain.com DC2008S-0
Server:  DC2008S-0.domain.com
Address:  10.1.1.3

_ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.domain.com     SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = DC2008E-0.domain.com
DC2008E-0.domain.com        internet address = 10.1.1.27

c:\Users\userName\Desktop\replication>nslookup -type=SRV _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.domain.com DC2008E-1
Server:  DC2008E-1.domain.com
Address:  10.1.1.28

_ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.domain.com     SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = DC2008E-0.domain.com
DC2008E-0.domain.com        internet address = 10.1.1.27
```

I also inspected the CNAME records from the root of the _MSDCS zone, this is the only place I found things to be odd.  The records themselves are all 100% correct, and the permissions look correct - at least, I should say, they all match between the 3 CNAME records and how each DC views the CNAME records.  However, the Owners are set differently.  DC2008S-0's record is owned by **SYSTEM**, DC2008E-0's record is owned by **DC2008E-0$**, and DC2008E-1's record is owned by **DC2008E-1$ (DOMAIN\DC2008E-1$)**.  This is the same no matter which DC I'm looking at the record on.

I don't know if that is pertinent at all, but it seems to be the ONLY thing I can find that doesn't match and/or follow the same pattern.  It may very well be a misnomer.

From DC2008E-0 I have also run **ipconfig /registerdns** and no errors were reported to the Event Viewer.  I have also run **nltest /dsregdns**

```
C:\Windows\system32>nltest /dsregdns
Flags: 0
Connection Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
The command completed successfully
```

This does not appear to fix the issue.

---

**Further Investigate**

It would appear that I had overlooked some output from the full DCDIAG set of tests I was running.  There are some more specific errors being reported.  And there's also much more granularity when it comes to how the DNS SRV records are being reported.

I'll post the relevant output from **dcdiag.exe /V /C /D /E /s:dc0**
(Actually, I have to post snippets as I'm hitting the character limit)

DC: DC2008S-0.domain.com
            Domain: domain.com
                  Adapter [00000012] Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection:

```
                 MAC address is 00:0C:29:9A:77:BA
                 IP Address is static 
                 IP address: 10.1.1.3
                 DNS servers:

                    10.1.1.3 (DC2008S-0) [Valid]
                    10.1.1.27 (DC2008E-0) [Valid]
                    127.0.0.1 (DC2008S-0) [Valid]
              The A host record(s) for this DC was found
              The SOA record for the Active Directory zone was found
              The Active Directory zone on this DC/DNS server was found primary
              Root zone on this DC/DNS server was not found


           TEST: Records registration (RReg)
              Network Adapter

              [00000012] Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection:

                 Matching CNAME record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 f11ae1a7-ab57-47d9-bf47-11eca1e33936._msdcs.domain.com

                 Matching A record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 DC2008S-0.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 _ldap._tcp.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 _ldap._tcp.5f315a51-10e4-4785-a4db-50312543bf35.domains._msdcs.domain.com
```

[...]

```
                 Matching CNAME record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 f11ae1a7-ab57-47d9-bf47-11eca1e33936._msdcs.domain.com

                 Matching A record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 DC2008S-0.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.5f315a51-10e4-4785-a4db-50312543bf35.domains._msdcs.domain.com
```

[...]

```
                 Warning: 
                 Missing CNAME record at DNS server 10.1.1.3: 
                 f11ae1a7-ab57-47d9-bf47-11eca1e33936._msdcs.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]

                 Warning: 
                 Missing A record at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 DC2008S-0.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]

                 Error: 
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 _ldap._tcp.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]

                 Error: 
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 _ldap._tcp.5f315a51-10e4-4785-a4db-50312543bf35.domains._msdcs.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]



           Error: Record registrations cannot be found for all the network

           adapters

           Total query time:0 min. 0 sec.. Total RPC connection

           time:0 min. 0 sec.

           Total WMI connection time:1 min. 3 sec. Total Netuse connection

           time:0 min. 0 sec.
```

[...]

```
        DC: DC2008E-0.domain.com
        Domain: domain.com
              Network adapters information:

              Adapter [00000007] vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter:

                 MAC address is 00:50:56:12:34:56
                 IP Address is static 
                 IP address: 10.1.1.27, fe80::3464:a8c8:13fa:7116
                 DNS servers:

                    10.1.1.3 (DC2008S-0) [Valid]
                    10.1.1.27 (DC2008E-0) [Valid]
                    127.0.0.1 (DC2008E-0) [Valid]
              The A host record(s) for this DC was found
              The SOA record for the Active Directory zone was found
              The Active Directory zone on this DC/DNS server was found primary
              Root zone on this DC/DNS server was not found

           TEST: Records registration (RReg)
              Network Adapter [00000007] vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter:

                 Matching CNAME record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 7ae71958-74b2-4dc3-bf0e-224ec881bafa._msdcs.domain.com

                 Matching A record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 DC2008E-0.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 _ldap._tcp.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 _ldap._tcp.5f315a51-10e4-4785-a4db-50312543bf35.domains._msdcs.domain.com
```

[...]

```
                 Matching CNAME record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 7ae71958-74b2-4dc3-bf0e-224ec881bafa._msdcs.domain.com

                 Matching A record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 DC2008E-0.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.5f315a51-10e4-4785-a4db-50312543bf35.domains._msdcs.domain.com
```

[...]

```
                 Warning: 
                 Missing CNAME record at DNS server 10.1.1.27: 
                 7ae71958-74b2-4dc3-bf0e-224ec881bafa._msdcs.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]

                 Warning: 
                 Missing A record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 DC2008E-0.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]

                 Error: 
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]

                 Error: 
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.5f315a51-10e4-4785-a4db-50312543bf35.domains._msdcs.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]
```

[...]

```
           Error: Record registrations cannot be found for all the network

           adapters

           Total query time:0 min. 4 sec.. Total RPC connection

           time:0 min. 0 sec.

           Total WMI connection time:1 min. 3 sec. Total Netuse connection

           time:0 min. 0 sec.
```

[...]

```
        DC: DC2008E-1.domain.com
        Domain: domain.com
              Network adapters information:

              Adapter [00000007] Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection:

                 MAC address is 00:0C:29:75:FF:46
                 IP Address is static 
                 IP address: 10.1.1.28, fe80::b81a:c109:24a0:9d3d
                 DNS servers:

                    10.1.1.3 (DC2008S-0) [Valid]
                    10.1.1.27 (DC2008E-0) [Valid]
                    127.0.0.1 (DC2008E-1) [Valid]
              The A host record(s) for this DC was found
              The SOA record for the Active Directory zone was found
              The Active Directory zone on this DC/DNS server was found primary
              Root zone on this DC/DNS server was not found

           TEST: Records registration (RReg)
              Network Adapter

              [00000007] Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection:

                 Matching CNAME record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 eafe6486-f76c-4900-8a20-46404fdbae57._msdcs.domain.com

                 Matching A record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 DC2008E-1.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 _ldap._tcp.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.3:
                 _ldap._tcp.5f315a51-10e4-4785-a4db-50312543bf35.domains._msdcs.domain.com
```

[...]

```
                 Matching CNAME record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 eafe6486-f76c-4900-8a20-46404fdbae57._msdcs.domain.com

                 Matching A record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 DC2008E-1.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.domain.com

                 Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 10.1.1.27:
                 _ldap._tcp.5f315a51-10e4-4785-a4db-50312543bf35.domains._msdcs.domain.com
```

[...]

```
                 Warning: 
                 Missing CNAME record at DNS server 10.1.1.28: 
                 eafe6486-f76c-4900-8a20-46404fdbae57._msdcs.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]

                 Warning: 
                 Missing A record at DNS server 10.1.1.28:
                 DC2008E-1.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]

                 Error: 
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.28:
                 _ldap._tcp.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]

                 Error: 
                 Missing SRV record at DNS server 10.1.1.28:
                 _ldap._tcp.5f315a51-10e4-4785-a4db-50312543bf35.domains._msdcs.domain.com
                 [Error details: 10054 (Type: Win32 - Description: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]


           Error: Record registrations cannot be found for all the network

           adapters

           Total query time:0 min. 0 sec.. Total RPC connection

           time:0 min. 0 sec.

           Total WMI connection time:0 min. 44 sec. Total Netuse connection

           time:0 min. 0 sec.
```

So it appears that there may be something going on with the NIC setup?  That's where I'm starting to lean now.

---

**NIC Configs**

DC2008S-0

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-9A-77-BA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.3(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.3
                                       10.1.1.27
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

DC2008E-0

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-12-34-56
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3464:a8c8:13fa:7116%15(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.27(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 335564886
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-4A-CD-9F-00-50-56-12-34-56
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       10.1.1.3
                                       10.1.1.27
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

DC2008E-1

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-75-FF-46
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b81a:c109:24a0:9d3d%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.28(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 251661353
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-23-34-D6-43-00-0C-29-75-FF-46
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       10.1.1.3
                                       10.1.1.27
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: What DNS servers are the NICs for the DCs configured to use? I generally force a DC to use other DCs as their primary DNS before themselves. For example, DC1 will point to DC2 and then DC1 and DC2 will point to DC1 and then DC2. This helps prevent a boot up issue where AD fails because it loaded before the DNS service loads.

Comment: I haven't updated the DNS servers since I started this whole thing as of yet.  So they still have the same settings they had before which is as follows:  The primary on all 3 DC is 10.1.1.3 (DC2008S-0) and the secondary is 10.1.1.27 (DC2008E-0), and then they all have an entry for 127.0.0.1 as the tertiary.  I am questioning that setup, but I'm not sure if that expressly leads into the RReg failure.

Comment: I added the original output from the NICs above.  After reviewing some additional articles on best practices for DNS settings on the NIC for a DC I think that do the loopback using the loopback address is wrong.  I've adjusted the DNS settings so that the first DNS server is another DC, the second being the server's own static ip address as a 'loopback' instead of the 127.0.0.1.  Will give everything some time in case records need to replicate or converge and then run dcdiag again.

Comment: Make sure to reboot each DC one by one (wait until fully booted before rebooting the next) after making the DNS change to ensure they've cleaned themselves up.

Comment: BTW, since we're going down my usual book of AD tricks, have you made sure everyone is time synchronized? Use `w32tm /monitor` to check time synchronization between DCs.

Comment: Ahh, I posted the 'answer' below, but that is good advice, I will make sure to do a reboot, but DCDIAG is now showing everything is good after the changes I outlined below - thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by removing IPv6 on the two DCs that had it running, and also by re-arranging the DNS configuration on the Network Cards.

DC2008S-0

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-9A-77-BA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.3(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.27
                                       10.1.1.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

DC2008E-0

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-12-34-56
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.27(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.28
                                       10.1.1.27
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

DC2008E-1

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-75-FF-46
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.28(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.27
                                       10.1.1.28
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```